# Inconsistant outputs on printing values

Tags: c++, memory, graph, iostream, cout

In this program I am cloning a graph in c++.
[This is the question that i am coding.](https://leetcode.com/problems/clone-graph/) 
This is my program and following it the issue and problem area.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define neighbours neighbors
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;

    Node() {
        val = 0;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }

    Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }

    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
};

#define neighbours neighbors
class Solution {
public:
    Node* cloneGraph(Node* node) 
    {
        // BFS
        queue <Node*> q;
        // add starting vec
        q.push(node);

        Node *curr;
        int value;
        vector <int> visited;
        unordered_map <int, Node*> umap;

        while(!q.empty())
        {
            curr = q.front();
            q.pop();
            visited.push_back(curr->val);
            //cout << curr->val << "-";
            // create new node
            Node *newNode = new Node(curr->val);
            // add new node val and addr to umap
            umap[value] = newNode;
            // clone neighbour list
            vector <Node*> nlist;
            //vector <Node*> list = curr->neighbours; // make copy of given list
            for(Node* node: curr->neighbours)
            {
                value = node->val;
                //cout << value << " ";
                // search in map first, if exists take addr else make and insert into                   
                // list
                if(umap.find(value) == umap.end())
                {
                    umap[value] = new Node(value);
                }
                nlist.push_back(umap[value]);
                if(find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), value) == visited.end())
                {
                    q.push(node);
                }
            }
            cout << endl;

            newNode->neighbours = nlist; // copy nlist to nodes list part
        }
        // starting of new node = umap[1];
        return umap[1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node ob1;
    Node ob2;
    ob1.val = 1;
    ob2.val = 2;
    vector <Node*> nlist;
    nlist.push_back(&ob1);
    ob2.neighbours = nlist;
    nlist.pop_back();
    nlist.push_back(&ob2);
    ob1.neighbours = nlist;
    Solution obj;
    Node *sv = obj.cloneGraph(&ob1);
    cout << sv->val << "-";
    for(Node *node : sv->neighbours)
    {
        cout << node->val << endl;
    }
    cout << &ob1 << " " << sv << endl;
}
```

When I comment out the last line my out put is

```
1-2
```

When I leave it as it is then the output is

```
1-0x7ffee561e4e0 0x7fb1ba402840
```

Also I just tried to comment out the `cout << endl;` which is towards the end of the `while` loop and also commented out the last statement of my program which gives an output

```
1-
```

*What is the reason for such strange behaviour?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`umap[value] = newNode;` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `value`.

In practice, `value` contains some garbage that happens to sit on the stack. Changes to seemingly unrelated parts of the program affect the contents of the stack, and thereby the initial value of `value`, and ultimately the way the aforementioned undefined behavior manifests itself.